# MYSQL - How to convert a string resulting from GROUP_CONCAT function into a digit

Tags: mysql, string, converters, group-concat, digits

I have been stuck for a while with this query and was wondering if anyone here knows what I may be doing wrong.

The problem I'm facing is that the following query sends me a 0 instead of a -5 and if I remove the "CAST" function, I get -05, so it would appear as if the string -05 is not being converted to -5, however if I replace the entire "GROUP_CONCAT" function by '-05' then the "CAST" function DOES convert -05 to -5... is there something I'm missing here?

```
SELECT CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(if(FIELD_ID = 8, LEFT(VALUE,3), NULL)) as SIGNED INTEGER) as 'user_timezone' 
FROM tn_cimy_uef_data 
WHERE user_id = '58';
```

Expected Result: -5
Actual Result: 0 (NOT GOOD)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(if(FIELD_ID = 8, LEFT(VALUE,3), NULL)) as 'user_timezone' 
FROM tn_cimy_uef_data 
WHERE user_id = '58';
```

Excpected Result: -05
Actual Result: -05 (GOOD)

```
SELECT CAST('-05') as 'user_timezone' 
FROM tn_cimy_uef_data 
WHERE user_id = '58';
```

Excpected Result: -5
Actual Result: -5 (GOOD)

The table looks like this (table tn_cimy_uef_data):

```
ID      USER_ID         FIELD_ID        VALUE
1       58              1               12121212
2       58              2               12121212
3       58              3               lorem ipsum
4       58              4               lorem ipsum
5       58              5               lorem ipsum
6       58              6               lorem ipsum
7       58              7               lorem ipsum
8       58              8               −05:00:00 -> America/Miami
9       58              9               lorem ipsum
10      58              10              12121212
```

I appreciate if anyone could shed some light in this darkness xD

Thanks, 
P

Comment: That's not a minus sign, it's Unicode code point 0x53C32

Comment: @Barmar lol… good eye!

Comment: http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html? says it's `U+2212 : MINUS SIGN`. You need to use a normal ASCII hyphen: `U+002D : HYPHEN-MINUS {hyphen or minus sign}`

Comment: That was perfect, indeed good eye. Once I replaced the "−" for a "-" everything started to work. Thanks!